# How to dynamically set orientation of pushed screen - React-Native-Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I would like to know how to dynamically change the orientation of a pushed screen using react-native-navigation.

I am using startSingleScreenApp with an appStyle of orientation: 'portrait' to force portrait screens. and I want to have just one of the pushed screens to use 'auto'

I have tried the following:

```
static navigatorStyle = {
   drawUnderTabBar: true,
   orientation: 'auto'
};
```

I have also tried:

```
componentWillMount() {
   this.props.navigator.setStyle({
      orientation: 'auto'
   });
};
```

I've even pushed to the screen using:

```
...
navigatorStyle: {
  orientation:'auto'
}
...
```

Is it even possible to dynamically change it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be achieved by using "React Native Orientation". It will listen to device orientation changes in React Native applications and programmatically set preferred orientation on a per screen basis. It works for both Android and iOS. Please find below link for more details:

```
https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation
```

You can use it as follows:

```
import Orientation from 'react-native-orientation';

// this locks the view to Portrait Mode. Need to add this in your screens 
 componentDidMount function
Orientation.lockToPortrait();
```

Or

```
// this locks the view to Landscape Mode. Need to add this in your screens 
 componentDidMount function
 Orientation.lockToLandscape();
```

You can find detailed instructions/guides in the shared link. You can add your logic accordingly as per your need. Hope it will help you.

Comment: I used this solution but the transition from a portrait screen to a landscape screen is not smooth and a little bit lag, what should be the right way?