# React native change orientation

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hi i'm new to learning react native, anyway i'm making an app with two screens, the thing is i wanna the first screen stay in ***portrait*** orientation but not the second screen. I want the second screen turn to ***landscape*** mode when i switch the app to that screen. Is there any simple way to do that.

Comment: Check this link out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47683591/react-native-different-styles-applied-on-orientation-change

Comment: maybe here => https://stackoverflow.com/a/51190913/9300663